# Laravel 5.1 blade is not working even after including laravel Collective

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

[image]**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

updated composer using artisian command `composer update` .then added

**app.php**

```
  'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,


        /*
        * Laravel Collective HTML
        */
        Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
        //App\Providers\AnnotationsServiceProvider::class,
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => [

        'App'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Artisan'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Bus'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
        'Cache'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
        'Config'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
        'Cookie'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
        'Crypt'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
        'DB'        => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
        'Eloquent'  => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
        'Event'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
        'File'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
        'Gate'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
        'Hash'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
        'Input'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
        'Inspiring' => Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring::class,
        'Lang'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
        'Log'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
        'Mail'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
        'Password'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
        'Queue'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
        'Redirect'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
        'Redis'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        'Request'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
        'Response'  => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
        'Route'     => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
        'Schema'    => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
        'Session'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
        'Storage'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'URL'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,

        //Two aliases for HTML Service Provider

        'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
        'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,

    ],
```

Then created my view pages like:-

**layouts/app.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Laravel Quickstart - Basic</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <!-- Navebar contents -->
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**tasks.blade.php**

```
[![@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <!-- Current Tasks -->
    @if(count($tasks) > 0)
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Current Tasks
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table table-striped task-table">

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
     @endif

    <!-- TODO: Current Tasks -->
    @endsection][1]][1]
```

**routes.php**
**[![Route::get('/', function () {
    //return view('welcome');
    $tasks = array('a', 'b', 'c');
    return view('tasks', ['tasks'=>$tasks]);
});][2]][2]**

[image]

[image]

Comment: whats with `[! [` before the `@extend` do?

Comment: have you tried naming it 'Task' ?

Comment: @luigonsec that does not matter PHP is case insensitive .

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu it most definitely is not case insensitive about namespaces and class names.

Comment: If you post a question and then later have a revelation and need to fundamentally change your question, just leave the original question as-is and ask a new question. You can reference the original question in your new question if you'd like (and if relevant), but don't try to delete your original question. Deletion is only appropriate if the question doesn't belong on Stack Overflow (like, if you asked about cat grooming techniques for cats belonging to programmers... you can delete that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to access the view directly, which is not how Laravel works. You need to setup the route and access that route, which returns the view that you want.

For example, go to `app/Http/routes.php`. This is your routes file. In it, you can add something like this:

```
// The "test" is the uri. Keep this in mind.
// Think of it as the appended URL.
// So, it would be something like www.example.com/test
Route::get('test', function () {

    // I am returning the view here.
    // Note that I am returning "tasks", not "tasks.blade.php".
    return view('tasks');

});
```

Then, based on your image, you would need to access this route here: http://localhost/laravel/public/test

If you change the URI to something like "tasks":

```
// Changing "tests" to "tasks"
Route::get('tasks', function () {

    // Note that I am returning "tasks", not "tasks.blade.php"
    return view('tasks');

});
```

Then you access it at http://localhost/laravel/public/tasks

Read the docs on routing for a full breakdown on the subject: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing

Comment: I was routing correctly,  but there is some problem in model, so for now I can say , I need to modify the question.for now I have assigned an array in route and it is working.

Comment: Can you tell me why there is no model class in laravel 5.1 ?

Comment: That is a completely different problem and question. You shouldn't be mixing different issues in the same question because it'll only cause confusion for future readers. Now, because you edited and changed your question, when people find this and read the answers, they're going to be reading answers that are completely unrelated to your new / edited problem. If you fixed your problem, you should mark the correct answer. If you have a new problem, you should then post a new question.

Comment: how I can delete this ? I am unable to delete this :(

Comment: flagged it for deletion

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu there should be a delete link at the bottom of your question.

Comment: @smartrahat I can not delete a question with upvotes :(

Comment: @smartrahat It needs 5 votes to delete this question, I am one please flag it based on this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311199/what-to-do-with-questions-which-are-asked-foolishly?cb=1

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu flagged.

Answer (score 4):

You may be missing `use App\Task;` at the top of your `routes.php` file.

I had the exact same issue, `Class 'Task' not found` and this fixed it.
Ensure that your `task::orderBy....` is the correct capitalisation too.

Here's the first route from mine for example:

```
use App\Task;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


/**
 * Display All Tasks
 */
Route::get('/', function () {
    $tasks = Task::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();

    return view('tasks', [
        'tasks' => $tasks
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure of:

- Name it **Task** instead of **task**
- Include `use App\Task` inside your **routes.php**
- Include namespace at the first line in **Task.php**: `namespace App;` (if you have the models in **App**, of course)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a **`@endif`** in your **`tasks.blade.php`** file

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <!-- Current Tasks -->
    @if(count($tasks) > 0){{--@endif for this section--}}
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Current Tasks
            </div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table table-striped task-table">

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif{{--Add @endif--}}
    <!-- TODO: Current Tasks -->
@endsection
```

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu can run this command **`php artisan view:clear`** it might be view cache problem

Comment: still no gain :( should I do anything after clearing cache using this command ?

Comment: Also which **`URL`** you are loading? Are you directly navigating to your blade file like your screenshot?

Comment: isnt it @stop instead of endsection?

Comment: @melvnberd here http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart check it , It is endsection in 5.1

Comment: sorry im used to laravel 4.2

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu no shouldn't do that your **`Routes`** are typically in **`/app/Http/routes.php`**. You can run **`php artisan route:list`** to see your available routes then you can navigate to that **`url`**. You can't just directly navigate to the **`blade file`**.

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA I have not worked on this from that day, I will try tomorrow and let you know.thanks for your response .

Answer (score 0):

and also don't forget to put this thing on your code in routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

    //your current code here

})
```